# PHP user log in, database authentication and redirect help needed

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, redirect

I'm a beginner developer stuck in a tough situation needing to deliver this project I haven't been able to grasp completely.

There is a page with a login button. When you press that button, it takes you to wp admin instead of verifying your given permission level in wp mysql database, and based on that transferring you to the appropriate web site. I figured out how to connect to database and verify user but I'm not sure how put in multiple parameters because there are 5 sections of privileges given to users. Based on their privileges they get sent to another part of the website. I'm using the header php function to redirect but I am unsure if I can include it in the same file and how do I tie this file to existing wp login page? Please help!

```
<?php

  error_reporting(0);
  session_start();
  class logmein {
  var $hostname_logon = 'localhost';     
  var $database_logon = '';      
  var $username_logon = '';      
  var $password_logon = '';      

  var $user_table = 'logon';         
  var $user_column = 'useremail';    
  var $pass_column = 'password';     
  var $user_level = 'userlevel';     
  var $encrypt = false;

  function dbconnect(){
    $connections = mysql_connect($this->hostname_logon,    $this->username_logon, $this->password_logon) or die ('Unabale to connect to   the database');
    mysql_select_db($this->database_logon) or die ('Unable to select   database!');
    return;
  }

  function login($table, $username, $password){

    $this->dbconnect();

    if($this->user_table == ""){
      $this->user_table = $table;
    }
    if($this->encrypt == true){
      $password = md5($password);
    }

    header("Location: https://example.com/members/index.php");
```

Comment: this doesn't help you btw `error_reporting(0);` nor does `or die ('string')` plus MD5 isn't considered safe to use as password hashing.

Comment: do you realize how broad this question is for what you have shown

Comment: look to the right of the screen. plenty of mysql related questions under `Related`. They looked it up for you. click on one.

Answer (score 1):

For your quick setup here us example [multi-user-role-based-login-in-php-with-mysql](http://www.techyari.in/2014/10/multi-user-role-based-login-in-php-with-mysql.html)

This site have mention everything about your needs. Use "roleid" column in user table so that you identify that user type is what.